# Kalman filter for stock price return

Tags: time-series, forecasting, finance, kalman-filter

I am trying to use the Kalman filter to predict daily stock returns, where I have access to about 2000 trading days of daily price data, denoted $y_t$ as well as simulations of the same dimension using Fractal Brownian Motion (FBM) and a Mutlifractal Random Walk (MRW). I have decided to combine the FBM and MRW in the KF algorithm and then use the actual price data $y_t$ to compute the MSE.

I am trying to model the process:

$$x_{t+1} = M x_t + w_k \\
y_t = H x_t + v_t$$

The formula I am using decides to use a 'frozen' covariance matrix, $P_{t+1}^a$, because of issues propagating. It is as follows:

Prediction:

$$x_{t+1}^f = Mx_t^f$$
$$P_{t+1}^f = P_b$$

Forecast step:

$$
K_{t+1} = P_bH^T(HP^bH^T + R_{t+1})^{-1} \\ 
x_{t+1}^a = x_{t+1}^f + K_{t+1}(y_{t+1} - x_{t+1}^f) \\
P_{t+1}^a = P^b
$$

where $H = I$, the identity matrix. The reason being is that I have the values for the stock prices (and hence returns) already meaning that I don't need to model/transform the states to observations.

The MSE was better using the KF, an order of magnitude lower than the MSE using just FBM or MRW but I wonder if I am computing this properly?

Is this correct? Is there a better way I should design this experiment? Am I using the KF properly?

I would really appreciate any criticism or guidance on this investigation

EDIT:

The matrix $M$ is a matrix that defines the data simulation process for FBM and the MRW. As the data has been provided to me I don't know this matrix $M$. In this model $x_t$ are returns as I am assuming a gaussian distribution and prices cannot be negative.

Comment: Hi: I think that your question  ( atleast the part regarding the KF ) could be better understood if you wrote down the observation equation and state equation that's being used.  Also, are $x_t$ prices or returns ? Also, what's $M$ ?

Comment: Hi, please see the updates to the question to answer your questions. $x_t$ are returns and $M$ is an unknown matrix that generates the simulated data via FBM and MRW (data provided by a research group to me. Because I have the data I believe that it isn't that relevant to the actual KF algorithm

Comment: I'll have to look the  updating equations up to see if they were right but what's $R_{t+1}$. Don't you have to update that also ? It also looks, $P^{a}_{t+1}$ never changes ? Is that right ?

Comment: $R_{t+1}$ is the covariance matrix of the observation but I am unsure how exactly this is updated. My thought process was that it isn't and I just use the next diagonal component of this matrix at each new time step. $P_{t+1}^a$ doesn't change, that's right. It is frozen because the update step for it can become computationally expensive and slow down the procedure. This adjustment leads to the process of Optimal Interpolation

Comment: That's not correct for $R_{t+1}$. Even if your freezing the initial covariance, $cov(w_{k}$ you need to update the whole matrix during each update. $R_{t+1} = M cov(x_{t+1}) M^{\prime} + cov(w_{k})$. I don't have time right now but sometime tonight I will send you some intro document on the KF that explains the updating equations.

Comment: The American Statistician paper at this link http://fang.faculty.ku.edu/KF-PF.html is a pretty nice ( it's old but it hasn't changed ) explanation of the updating equations for the KF. There are others there also that may be useful but I'm not familiar with them. I hope it helps.